# @ControllerAdvice is not returning json response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Whenever my controller is throwing the exception, it is not not returning the response in json format.

It is giving Whitelabel Error Page

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
```

My controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = GENERATE_IMAGE, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public byte[] get(@PathVariable("input") String input) throws IOException {
    if (true) {
        throw new BusinessValidationFailureException("sdfsdfsd");
    }
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = service.generate(input);
    return ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
}
```

And my controller advice is:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class WickesGlobalExceptionMapper extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(BusinessValidationFailureException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity handleBusinessException(BusinessValidationFailureException ex, WebRequest request) {

        ErrorResource error = new ErrorResource("InvalidRequest", ex.getMessage(), null);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, error, headers, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, request);
    }
}
```

I tried few other possibility but I got the same error page all the time.

I get below exception in the server:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:259) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:203) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:384) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:59) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
```

Comment: I think that your controller advice is throwing an exception. Please add the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since controller produces MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE, controlleradvice should also produce the same mediatype. I removed produces from requestmapping and set the content type in the response, and it worked.

```
@RequestMapping(value = GENERATE_BARCODE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity get(@PathVariable("input") String barcodeInput) throws IOException {
    byte[] resonse = service.generate(barcodeInput);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
    return new ResponseEntity(resonse, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with your original question?  This will not have any effect on the error response.

Answer (score 8):

You did not show the *handleExceptionInternal* method implementation, this does return an object?

**Edit**: I was wrong about the `@RestControllerAdvice`, removed it from the answer.

Let's assume you want to return an object of type `ErrorData` (this is not clear from your post). So you could use:

```
@ExceptionHandler(BusinessValidationFailureException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ErrorData> handleBusinessException(BusinessValidationFailureException e) {
  ErrorData errorData = createYourErrorData();
  return new ResponseEntity(errorData, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
}
```

I just tried this and got the correct stataus code back together with the data object in JSON.

Comment: using RestControllerAdvice is same as ControllerAdvice and ResponseBody. It's just a saving of one line. Functionality wise I doubt it will make a difference.